# Как коротко можно написать код python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал код, которого здесь нет и необходимо проверить условие, но не хочу, чтобы это выглядело примерно так, как внизу, есть другие предложения?

```
if await func1(text) == False and await func2(text) == False and await func3(text) == False:
    print('string is good')
else:
    print('error')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Кажется, самая короткая форма будет такая:

```
if not any([await func1(text), await func2(text), await func3(text)]):
    print('string is good')
else:
    print('error')
```

Comment: Отличный вариант :)

Comment: @gil9red Ну, я ещё что-то помню смутно про инвертирование `or` и `and` )

Comment: Отличный вариант :)

Answer (score 5):

Например так:

```
if not await func1(text) and not await func2(text) and not await func3(text):
    print('string is good')
else:
    print('error')
```

Или через `all`:

```
if all([not await func1(text), not await func2(text), not await func3(text)]:
    print('string is good')
else:
    print('error')
```

Comment: А точно `await not`, а не `not await`? Или без разницы вообще?

Comment: @CrazyElf, блин, точно `not await` :)

Comment: можно положить функции в список и итерировать по нему

Answer (score 3):

можно еще короче)

```
print(["string is good", "error"][any([await x("text") for x in (func1, func2, func3)])])
```

Comment: )) писали ответ одновременно ))

Comment: Кст, в случаи for можно не писать квадратные скобки, т.е. выражение сделать генератором: `any(await x("text") for x in (func1, func2, func3))`

Comment: Это очень и очень! ))

Comment: print(["string is good", "error"][any(await x("text") for x in (func1, func2, func3))])
TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable

Answer (score 3):

Ну это пожалуй слегка короче:

```
print('error' if any(await f(text) for f in (func1, func2, func3)) else 'string is good')
```

Хотя возможно читаемость и хромает, но я убрал лишний `print`. Ну разве не прекрасно?

Comment: Кст, в случаи for можно не писать квадратные скобки, т.е. выражение сделать генератором: `any(await x("text") for x in (func1, func2, func3))`

Comment: @gil9red  спасибо, подправвил

Comment: Да, это серьёзно короткий код, но запомнить это куда сложнее, но всё же ли спасибо Вам)